# Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): The files c or directory could not be found

Tags: running-other-programs

I am working with scriptcase php code generator, which is installed in a server but i access it via the web. It was fine till someone logged off the administrator of the server (which is the user I use). I restarted the server and logged on as admin, but now I cant access scriptcase from chrome! It shows:

```
Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): The file or directory could not be found.
```

What should i do?![enter image description here]

Answer (score 9):

Big one I see that causes this is filename.  If you have a SPACE then any number such as 'Site 2' the file path with look like something/Site%202/index.html  This is because spaces or rendered as %20, and if another number is immediately following that it will try to read it as %202. Fix is you never use spaces in your filenames.

Answer (score 6):

I fixed the same problem on Google Chrome with the following:

1. Choose **Customize and control Google Chrome** (the button in the top right corner).
2. Choose **Settings**.
3. Go to **Extensions**.
4. Unmark all the extensions there. (They should show as **Enable** instead of **Enabled**.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it actually solved by it self..i still don't understand why it even happened. However i'm glad you posted this so i'm gonna keep it in mind just in case i run through it again :)

Comment: @Mirela The answer should not be accepted since it didn't solve your problem. This is misleading.

Comment: I found this problem in AdBlock google chrome's extension. After disabling this extension, problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue as follows:

removed from chrome extension and install ext again.
It will work ISA

Answer (score 0):

The below are the typical situation where we shall get ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND even file avail in respective folder.

```
Code:
@font-face {
    font-family: Eau_Sans_Bold;
    src: url("/fonts/eau_sans_bold.otf") format("opentype");
}
Error:
 GET file:///C:/fonts/eau_sans_bold.otf net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Answer or Solution.:
@font-face {
    font-family: Eau_Sans_Book;
    src: url("../fonts/eau_sans_book.otf") format("opentype");  
}

Basically browser not able to pick if we metion just /font/. We should to mention ../fonts/ This will work. So, we wont get ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is an HTML file where you are using  file://FileName then using a CDN like src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js" will not work.

You will have to include the .js file in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: the error was `File not found`, while opening `HTML` files in chrome, but I resolved it as follows:

BEFORE:

1) I saved a html file `abc.html` in a folder name `C#`.

2) When I was opening the `abc.html` in Google Chrome, it was showing error as "file not found". But it was working fine on Firefox and Internet Explorer.

AFTER:

3) What I did then is, I simply changed the folder name `C#` to `csharp`  without space and re opened it in Chrome. It worked.

4) The moral is: Make sure you don't give any space in a folder name as some browsers don't support it.