# Images doesn't show , and I can't make my sections appear side by side

Tags: html, css

**Code:**
I have snapshot of my code at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmfig.jpg) location. There are 3 pictures of `index.html`, `main.css` and `actual page`"

Please ignore different language in the paragraph tags. You can see that I have linked the images properly (as I think I have done) but the images don't show and also the sections aren't side by side, but I have written the code to make them appear like so.

Comment: You are looking for them outside of the website folder. Remove ../ on your img tags and that should do it.

Comment: I did remove it, but its still same , also I found error , my "facebook-wrap" image didnt have  ".png", I edited the code but it's still same, neither of the three images are showing .

Comment: Please do not post code as images. Use code blocks for that.

Comment: Improve formatting

Comment: It looks like a bad path problem. Check image path. Where do you have your images? Is there any chance we can see the site live in order to check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the reason you are not seeing your images is due to the path being wrong make sure you are using the correct path maybe even remove one of the ../ in the file name.

Comment: I did remove it, but its still same , also I found error , my "facebook-wrap" image didnt have ".png", I edited the code but it's still same, neither of the three images are showing

Comment: Also try adding class to each section and doing the css that way. Maybe it is placing them static and since your using indent-1 for both sections and floating them left it is just placing it that way. You didn't close our parent section element either the one with the class="indent-1"

Comment: @TornikeShelia did you remove both of them. and just use img/filename.png

Comment: my Image src looks like this now -> <img src = "img/profile.jpg"> but nothing changes , I added classes to each of the sections and added wrapper class to the main section , in each section I floated one to the left, one to the right but still the code didnt react. (it seemed like something was bugged cauz nothing changed even tho I edited sections classes and floats, so I changed some text in the paragraph just to make sure that code worked and the code did change in the page . so theres something wrong with the logic of Sections and Image src's but what is it ? )

Comment: also, since my images are clickable links (which takes the user to the full image ), I clicked on the profile-image and it took me the error page , the error says -> Your file was not found

It may have been moved or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Yes those images should appear with what you got not understanding that at all. Have you tried just taking out the images from the img folder and placing them in the same root as the index.html. And just use <img src="profile.jpg" /> just to test it out and see if it works. This is a silly question but, have to ask pal but, did you also change the path in the link element also. @TornikeShelia

Comment: also, I checked the file img, on my pc and everything seems to be correct, all the images are there.

Comment: Are you using chrome @TornikeShelia

Comment: yes I'm using chrome to preview the page, to answer your earlier question I just tried to move the picture to the main directory and just use the <img src="profile.jpg" >, but its still same . To make sure something isn't bugged, I removed the whole img code after that and the page did react correctly and removed the blank image it was showing, so I'm not really getting whats the problem :\ I do think that something is bugged .

Comment: I searched for the same error and came across this please look at first answer. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015789/error-6-neterr-file-not-found-the-file-or-directory-could-not-be-found)

Comment: Other than that pal that is strange that this is going on so, I am hoping this helps you. Also try Firefox cause it seems to me when I am using html and Chrome it seems to take long to render new code then it would when using Firefox.

Comment: I will see that right after I take my dog out, anyways , thanks for the answer mate , appreciated . I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: Ok sounds good will keep an eye out for your response hopefully its a good one.

Comment: It didn't help, so basically the topic was saying to uncheck the extensions on google chrome which I did but the problem didn's solve, then I installed the mozilla firefox and it's same, the images are't showing, so thanks for your help mate, but theres bug I think either with Atom (text editor I'm currently using), or with images I'm using.

Comment: Nope, not with the images . just downloaded random Image from google and same problem, I'll try and use different text editor and see what happens.

Comment: Ya download NotePad++

Comment: Wow, I fixed the problem, I uploaded the image on the web (on some image upload website ) ,got the html code for the image and pasted it in my code and now the image is showing, so I think somehow the path that I'm writting in my code is incorrect , but I don't know why.

Comment: I should have thought of that (Uploading the image on the web) earlier.

Comment: Thats awesome nice job and yes there must be something wrong with the path